# How to calculate $\int_0^1 e^x \; dx$ using Riemann sum.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I need to calculate 
$\int_0^1 e^x \; dx$ using Riemann sum.

Problem set gives a hint:"The sum is a geometric progression. You will need the limit $ \lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)$ . This can be evaluated putting h = 1/n and relating the limit to the derivative of $e^x$ at x = 0".

For future googling: problem comes from [problem set for MIT Open Courses, Single Variable Calculus, Unit 3 - Integration](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-3-the-definite-integral-and-its-applications/part-a-definition-of-the-definite-integral-and-first-fundamental-theorem/problem-set-6/MIT18_01SC_pset3prb.pdf), section 3B-Deﬁnite Integrals, problem 3B-6.

Comment: If you write down the Riemann sum, what do you get?

Comment: Hint: The problem set gives you a hint. Have you proven that the things that the hint states? Have you tried using the hint to help you solve the problem?

Comment: One Riemann sum approximation to $\int_a^b f(x) dx $ is $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(a+{k\over n}(b-a)) {1 \over n}$. Note that the integrand is increasing.

Comment: Arthur, I did the following reasoning: $\lim _{n\to \infty }n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right) = \frac{e^{\left(0+\Delta x\right)}-e^0}{\Delta \:x}=\frac{d}{dx}e^x\:at\:0\:=\:e^0\:=\:1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\int_0^1 e^x \; dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n e^{\frac k n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac1n \sum_{k=0}^n \left(e^{\frac 1 n}\right)^k$$

For the limit we have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }n\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{\left(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)}{\frac1n}=\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=1$$

and we can deduce that by definition of derivative or by l'Hopital.

Comment: I got to both of those conclusions, but not sure, how to tie them together.

Comment: Recall that by geometric series $$\sum_0^n r^k=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$ then let $r=e^{1/n}$ and finally take the limit.

Comment: Ok, applying the formula for series $\sum_0^n r^k=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$ , and provided $\lim_{n\to \infty }$ I got $ \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right)}{-\frac{1}{n}}=-\left(1-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}-1=e-1=e^1-e^0 $ . This agrees with FTC $\int _0^1\:e^xdx\:=\:e^1-e^0$ . Correct?

Comment: The result is correct but you need to use $r=e^{1/n}$ in the geometric series.

Comment: @user  when r is $e^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $r^n$ is just e, so infinite sum is ${\frac{a}{1-r}}*(e-1)$ not ${\frac{a}{1-r}}$ ?

Comment: @eugene The finite sum is $$\frac{e^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}$$ and the numerator tends to $(e-1)$.